# Is it possible to see the # of auth verification emails sent in Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In the Firebase Authentication, there's a [limitation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits?hl=ja#email_sending_limits) for the number of the email we can send, so I'd like to see the number of emails sent daily basis.

It seems impossible in the Firebase console, and I also checked the Google Cloud console but couldn't find it. Does anyone know if it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

I don't think there's any place to see how many emails of any type have been sent in the Firebase or Cloud console. Given the quota it sounds like a reasonable wish, so I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) for it.